# Use specific xml files in production vs development

Tags: java, spring, maven

We have a maven based Spring Web-Application. All the web-calls are `Restful` and need authentication. But for development purpose, it is a pain to do all the needful. So for the development cycle, it is preferred to not have any security.

Using a maven flag or something, how do we generate separate builds for production and development?

All the security related stuff are in `web.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`. We can have 2 copies (one for development and the other for production). In the maven build, what is the simplest way to include the necessary files and omit others.

PS: I have seen examples of doing above using assembly plugin. I do not need all that but just a simple way to do it. I am using `maven-war-plugin` to generate war file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use profiles. You define them in your pom.xml (see below) and then when you build you include them. For command line this is simply

```
mvn -P <profile> <target>
```

most IDE's provide a way to set a profile.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <!-- default -->
    <webXmlPath>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web-test.xml</webXmlPath>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Production</id>
        <properties>
            <webXmlPath>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXmlPath>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
    <id>Accept</id>
        <properties>
            <webXmlPath>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web-accept.xml</webXmlPath>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>${artifactId}-accept</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${webXmlPath}</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```